# Выборка с бд

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени!

Есть таблица "user", в ней ячейка "last_dates", куда пишем последнюю дату входа в Unix.
Как выбрать пользователей, которые не заходили неделю?

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT * FROM user  WHERE last_dates <= ( last_dates + 604800)
```

не работает, а если подставить конкретное, число работает.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE lastdates <= 1421839523
```

Как выбрать пользователей в таблице более 10к строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM user  WHERE last_dates <= ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800)`

По документации - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() без параметра возвращает текущее время в формате UNIX.

Comment: Погодите, это не то.
 
По-вашему, проверка идет от сегодня, а нужно от last_dates.

Comment: @lexx, изменил ответ. Берем время "сейчас" и отнимаем неделю - получаем время неделю назад (то, что в скобках), сравниваем последний вход, если он меньше - значит вход был раньше, чем ровно неделю назад.

Comment: Спасибо) теперь понял